# selecting all but the last X rows from a join in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with some maintenance on my database. We have a table A and a table B with a one-to-many relationship. Right now there are between 1 and 10 rows for every row in table B and I want to see every row except the 5 most recent. If there are 5 or less rows in B from any row in A, I don't want to see it because I don't care about that data.

Here's the query I have so far:

```
WITH cte (id, number)
AS
(
    SELECT A.id, COUNT(*)
    FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.a
    GROUP BY A.id
)
SELECT A.id, B.id, number
FROM cte c 
INNER JOIN B ON B.a=c.id
WHERE number > 5
ORDER BY A.id, B.id DESC;
GO
```

It will give me the IDs of the rows in A and B, and the number is just to help me see what is going on (it will be 10 if there are 10 matching rows, 9 if 9, etc).

I just don't really know where to go next. I have a list of rows in A and their matches in B and I want to see only the last 5 rows in B for every row in A. My data might look like this:

```
A | B | number
---------
1 | 7 | 7
1 | 6 | 7
1 | 5 | 7
1 | 4 | 7
1 | 3 | 7
1 | 2 | 7
1 | 1 | 7
2 | 9 | 2
2 | 8 | 2
```

And what I want is this:

```
A | B | number
---------
1 | 2 | 7
1 | 1 | 7
```

So really my question is - how can I *filter out* the last 5 rows in B for every row in A like this? I don't even know if I am heading in the right direction with what I've got so far, but it seemed like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Why not use ROW_NUMBER with a partition and then add a where predicate to only view those rows > 5 or whatever.

Comment: I just didn't know that those concepts existed, but thanks - looks like I have a solution now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.A ORDER BY b.id DESC) AS RowNum, ... other columns from b ...
    FROM dbo.B as b
) x
WHERE x.RowNum > 5
```

Note: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION b.A ORDER BY B.id DESC)` will start numbering rows from 1 for every `b.A` in descending order => last row will have `RowNum` = 1, last but one row will have `RowNum` = 2, etc.

Comment: Yep - this looks like it does the trick, thank you very much.

Btw, minor syntax error there ... it's PARTITION *BY*.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte (id, number) AS ( SELECT A.id, COUNT(*) FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.a GROUP BY A.id ) 
SELECT TOP 5 A.id, B.id, number FROM cte c 
INNER JOIN B ON B.a=c.id 
WHERE number > 5 ORDER BY A.id ASC, B.id ASC; GO
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, it just gives me the top 5 rows. In my test data example, it would end up giving me just the first 5 rows from my initial query.

Comment: It is always a good habit to also explain the solution, rather than just posting code.